# Avoid character casting of entire matrix after transposition

Tags: r, matrix, type-conversion, transpose

I have a matrix made like this:

```
      Sample_1    Sample_2
Class LV          M                         
X1    481023.9    2352.3                         
X2    5018243     NA                         
X3    2607193     7234.5                         
X4    NA          823
```

and I read it with

```
X <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=T,row.names=1,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Because of the first row being `characters` the entire columns are considered as such. I then need to transpose the matrix and when I do so the whole matrix is still considered as `character` while I want it as `numeric`.

I have tried sever ways to tackle the problem but they are all pretty dirty (e.g. I write the transpose on a csv and then read it back).

What I have tried with no success:

```
xs <- as.data.frame(t(X),stringsAsFactors=F)  #1

xs <- t(X)                                    #2
xs <- data.frame(xs,stringsAsFactors=F)       

xs <- as.data.frame(t(X[-1,]))                #3 it doesn't work even excluding the infamous row!
```

Does any of you have a better alternative?

Comment: You can try with `skip=2`, `header=FALSE`, and then change the column names

Comment: But in this case I would need to either input manually "Sample_1","Sample_2"... or read the file again

Comment: You can then read just the column names using `nrows = 1` and rename your data set.